# In GEE replace NoData value with value Zero in an image with only one band

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, image, nodata

I have the following code in GEE: I am trying to replace the NoData values with Zeros.

```
var mag_nbr = float_predictor_variables.select(['MAG_NBR'])
var mag_nbrZero = mag_nbr.where({
        test: mag_nbr.eq(null),
        value:0,
  });
```

However, I have the following error:

> Image (Error)
> Parameter 'image2' is required.

Answer (score 1):

The unmask function does it:

```
var mask_mag_nbr = mag_nbr.lte(0);
var mag_nbr_masked = mag_nbr.updateMask(mask_mag_nbr)
var imgUnmasked = mag_nbr_masked.unmask(0);
```

The documentation was pretty clear:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-unmask